# How to add Conditional CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

I am trying to make a Chatbox where if the sender's message is less than the full width of the chat-box it should have `margin-left:auto` to make it go to the left side, otherwise it should have a `margin-left:30px` to have consistency in the design.

```
 .transcription-texts {
  height: 70vh;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  direction: rtl;

  .speaker-turn {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    direction: ltr;

    .speaker-font {
      color: white;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;

      &.ch1 {
        margin-left: auto; //here needs to be margin-left:30px when full width
        background-color: #68a4ff;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      }
      &.ch2 {
        background-color: #0041a4;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        margin-right: 30px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Edit this how I solved the problem:

HTML:

```
if (each.ch === "ch1") {
  return (
    <div className={`speaker-turn customer`}>
      <span className="speaker-font ch1">{each.t}</span>
      <img src={CustomerIcon} />
    </div>
  );
} else if (each.ch === "ch2") {
  return (
    <div className={`speaker-turn`}>
      <img src={AgentIconDark} />
      <span className="speaker-font ch2">{each.t}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS:

```
.transcription-texts {
  height: 70vh;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  direction: rtl;

  .speaker-turn {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    direction: ltr;

    &.customer {
      justify-content: end;
    }

    .speaker-font {
      color: white;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 10px 30px 10px 10px;

      &.ch1 {
        margin-left: 30px;
        background-color: #68a4ff;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
      }
      &.ch2 {
        background-color: #0041a4;
        border-radius: 20px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        margin-right: 30px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some HTML as well, or better still a [MCVE]? CSS is pretty much declarative and is ignorant of content. It will never know if an element is full width or not. You are probably better off with `absolute` positioning or floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could always give it a margin-left of 30px, or even a max-width of 100% - 30px and then just use flex to align it to the right

Comment: Thanks I just added a class to the customer and set its justify-content:end . That solved the problem. I am editing my question to show what I did according to your answer